# Is there a way to call a function by setting its attribute?

Tags: javascript

I have an object which looks like this:

```js
const trigger = {
    // ...
    addEventListener: function(evt, cb) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

It has an event registration system by calling `addEventListener`.

I also want it can be called by `trigger.onxxx = xxx`(the function is started with `on`) for legacy purposes. How can I do that?

Such as if I write

```js
const handleTouch = function() { /* ... */ };
trigger.ontouch = handleTouch;
```

And this is what it actually does:

```js
trigger.addEventListener('touch', handleTouch);
```

I know I can use a setter to call a function, but in this case the function name is random.

Is there a way to automatically calling the function when I set it

or I have to hard code them separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a Proxy, and when a property is set, check if its name starts with `on`. If it was, call the `addEventListener` method, otherwise modify the underlying object (if that could ever occur):

```js
const addEventListener = function(evt, cb) {
  console.log('adding listener for', evt);
}

const trigger = {
  addEventListener,
  // other properties
};

const proxy = new Proxy(trigger, {
  set(target, prop, newVal) {
    if (prop.startsWith('on')) {
      return addEventListener(prop.slice(2), newVal);
    }
    return target[prop] = newVal;
  }
});

proxy.onfoo = () => 'on foo';
proxy.addEventListener('foo', () => 'on foo');
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing, I don't know this exists! Thank you so much, again! So I can use the `proxy` object exactly like the original `trigger`? Nothing else is changed?

Comment: Yes - any trap that is not triggered by the Proxy is forwarded on to the original object. (So if you want *getting* the `on` properties to result in the attached function being returned, you'll want to put them onto the `trigger` object when `addEventListener` runs). But there are disadvantages: (1) proxies are pretty slow (2) they aren't transpilable

Comment: @CertainPerformance While Proxies are cool, do you think this mechanism of adding functionality to an object would get confusing / unexpected quite quickly?

Comment: @ben Could be. I never use them myself. I think their main use is to work around badly designed APIs and requirements. (Yes, I think event on- properties are silly, there are too many events; too many properties.) They're an X/Y solution, but without them, some things would be just *impossible* to achieve

Comment: Out of interest, why are they not transpileable?

Comment: @Ben There's just no other mechanism for intercepting *general* property lookup / setting / calling (among other available traps). If the Proxy object isn't available, there's no way to build one that does the same thing.